# Выборка/Фильтр слов из массива LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Имеется список строк:

```cs
 List<string> Names = new List<string> {"Horn","Horrible","GuaRd","exampl","GreGOry"};
```

Мне нужно отфильтровать слова по таким критериям:
  Чтобы первая буква слова была заглавной, а все остальные маленькими.
  Т.Е мне нужно получить: Horn,Horrible.

Вот мои наброски, но так и не докопался как проверить последующие символы:

```
Names.Where(x => char.IsUpper(x[0]))
```

Пробовал делать так:

```
Names.Where(x => char.IsUpper(x[0])).All(word=>word.Skip(1).Where(x=>char.isLower(x)));
```

Но тоже не получилось.

Comment: `var res = Names.Where(n => n.ToCharArray().Count(c => char.IsUpper(c)) == 1 && char.IsUpper(n.First()));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `All` возвращает `bool` - для получения самих элементов вместо него можно воспользоваться `Where`, как и в других случаях:

```
Names.Where(word => char.IsUpper(word[0])).Where(word => word.Skip(1).All(char.IsLower))
```

А можно оба `Where` объединить в один:

```
Names.Where(word => char.IsUpper(word[0]) && word.Skip(1).All(char.IsLower))
```

Comment: Больше спасибо! Разобрался)

Answer (score 2):

В дотнете есть специальный метод [TextInfo.ToTitleCase](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase?view=netcore-3.1).

```
var names = new List<string> { "Horn", "Horrible", "GuaRd", "exampl", "GreGOry" };

var textInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US").TextInfo;

var titleNames = names.Where(name => name == textInfo.ToTitleCase(name));

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", titleNames));
```